# SvelteKit - VSCode with monorepo open incorrectly interprets relative SCSS import in Vite preprocessor config that compiles correctly

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass, svelte, vite

I am trying to auto import my SCSS variables to every .svelte file. To do this, I simply added this to the Vite preprocessor config:

`vite.config.ts`

```
css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
        scss: {
            additionalData: `@use 'sass:color'; @import 'src/styles/_values.scss';`
        }
    }
}
```

This compiles successfully and runs as intended. VSCode, however, throws errors in every .svelte file with SCSS. I am working in a monorepo, with the following structure:

```
project
|_ client
    |_ src
         |_ styles
               |_ _values.scss
         |_ ...
|_ api
     |_ ...
```

Therefore, VSCode does not recognize `src/styles/_values.scss`. If I change the path in the preprocessor config to `client/src/styles/_values.scss`, then VSCode reports no errors, but of course, the project does not compile.

I came up with this hacky solution that uses an absolute path to satisfy both the compiler and VSCode:

`svelte.config.js`

```
import path from 'path';
const __filename = new URL(import.meta.url).pathname;
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

const configPath = path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'styles', '_values.scss');

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    preprocess: sveltePreprocess({
        scss: {
            prependData: `@use 'sass:color'; @import '${configPath}';`
        }
    }),

    kit: {
        adapter: adapter()
    }
};

export default config;
```

However, this solution didn't work with the Vite preprocessor for some reason, so it required the use of `svelte-preprocess`.

I am unhappy with this solution because it requires an unnecessary dependency for the sake of resolving an editor bug. Is there a non-hacky way of solving this problem?

Thanks.